# Desktop not working Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: unity, 14.04, desktop-environments

I'm using Unity for quite some time now but for the past few days now I do not see anything on my Desktop, Unity itself seems to be working fine, my Launcher still works and my top-bar works fine as well.
However nothing from my home/Desktop folder appears on my Desktop and the Background image is the same as my lock screen image and I am not able to change it.

I tried using the Gnome desktop environment but the problem preexists.
I also tried to reinstall unity, ubuntu-desktop and my graphics card driver, nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Does the problem still exist if you create a test account and log in to that?

Comment: Yes it does still exist after adding a new user and logging in with it.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have to boot other (presumably new) `$HOME` folder after **you was reinstalled twice** your system. Perhaps you need to boot from some old kernel if you do not cleaned these kernels.
Look at your *GRUB screen* > *Advanced boot configurations* ...

Comment: I tried using different kernels, it still didn't work with any of thoe I had stored. How would I use a different home folder?

Comment: you could reinstall with altering (additional) partition and old do not mounted by default, look your GParted.